# Getting CORS error on implementation of Google tag manger in Fiori launchpad

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, sap-fiori

We have recently added Google tag manager to Fiori launchpad following the steps present in this [Blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/09/google-analytics-for-fiori-launchpad/) , But we are facing CORS issue while pushing the required data to window.datalayer.

If we are adding tag manager snippet to a SAP UI5 application and run it directly, then there is no error. But if we are running the application from Fiori launchpad then CORS error occurs.

Error :
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.google-analytics.com/j/collect?........' from origin 'https://firoi.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Can anyone please let us know what should be done in this case.

Regards,

Arpita Priyadarshinee

Comment: Hi @Arpita Is there any chance you've resolved the problem? It looks like we have the same issue and Google themselves don't feel like answering...

Comment: Hi.. the problem is with fiori launch pad in my case which is resolved in higher version . Please check this https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2402